# Adding a TextEdit to a column to a DevExpress GridView at runtime

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to add a TextEdit to a column on a  DevExpress GridView at runtime, this is what I have got (copied pretty much from some auto-generated designer code).

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit commentTextEdit 
      = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit();
gvwEnquiryList.Columns["Comments"].ColumnEdit = commentTextEdit;
ctlEnquiryList.RepositoryItems.Add(commentTextEdit);
```

What have I missed? (cos it doesn't work, "Comments" is still just a normal column)

Answer (score 1):

Using code below I was able to add a TextEdit column to my text field. I didn't need to use the RepositoryItems.Add function.

```
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit commentTextEdit = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit();
        commentTextEdit.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        commentTextEdit.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        commentTextEdit.Name = "commentTextEdit";

        this.comments.ColumnEdit = commentTextEdit;
```

Comment: Ah ha, maybe it needs the name - I'll try that.